# Using std::string in 64-bit app: "The application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, stdstring

I have a C++ Visual Studio project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1 = "This is a string";
    cout << "s1  is: " << s1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I change the project platform in the Configuration Manager to **x64** I get the runtime error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b).

Clicking on OK gives the message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FB4FB72100 (ntdll.dll) in MyConsoleApplication.exe: 0xC000007B:  %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0x.

This is probably some x86\x64 conflict, but I couldn't find any reference about using `std::string` in 64-bit applications.

Any idea?

Comment: What makes you think the error is related to `std::string` ?

Comment: Which Visual Studio? When you created the x64 configuration, did you choose to copy all settings from the already existing Win32 configuration?

Comment: @ Beta Carotin- when I delete #include <string> I don't get this error...

Comment: @ Banex- Visual Studio 2012, and yes, I did.

Comment: If you delete "#include <string>" I imagine your error would be along the lines of undefined string. Are you running on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: @Rootix- you're right, I deleted the string instance as well... and yes, I'm running on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: This is certainly not related to the use of `std::string` itself in an x64 environment. `0xc00007b` is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`, so it could be some DLL or files are corrupted. If you can't find any better solution, I'd suggest repairing Visual Studio.

Comment: @Banex, this was indeed the issue- thank you! I've posted your comment as answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Reposting my comment as answer)*

This is certainly not related to the use of `std::string` itself in an x64 environment. `0xc00007b` is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`, so it could be some DLL or files are corrupted.

This can be easily solved by repairing or reinstalling Visual Studio.